# How to decide the class that should be built for a problem statement?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm writing a code for blackjack, using the classes and other oops concept. Currently I'm stuck on how to decide what classes it will have.

Following are the rules of blackjack:

1.Create a deck of 52 cards

2.Shuffle the deck

3.Ask the Player for their bet

4.Make sure that the Player’s bet does not exceed their available chips

5.Deal two cards to the Dealer and two cards to the Player

6.Show only one of the Dealer’s cards, the other remains hidden

7.Show both of the Player’s cards

8.Ask the Player if they wish to Hit, and take another card

9.If the Player’s hand doesn’t Bust (go over 21), ask if they’d like to Hit again.

10.If a Player Stands, play the Dealer’s hand. The dealer will always Hit until the Dealer’s value meets or exceeds 17

11.Determine the winner and adjust the Player’s chips accordingly

12.Ask the Player if they’d like to play again

I'm new to coding and oops, kindly help

**NOTE**: this is not a homework problem, as there are many solution on github, which i can copy submit if required. I Just want to learn oops and classes. I don't seek a solution, I'm seeking a correct thought process

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may find this link useful: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). As it stands your question is quite broad and unclear, it may help to show what you've come up with already and where specifically you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I'll do the needful.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have edited my question, I don't seek a complete solution, what i seek is how to think about creating classes, once that gets cleared, i will try to implement it and comeback with my further doubts. I am seeking right thought process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a difficult process; usually, the first step is to identify the nouns in the description of the project, that gives you a starting point from where to think about the shape you will give to your code, and how you see these objects interacting.

From your description, we could list the following nouns:

**Deck, Player, Bet, Chips, Cards, Dealer, Hand, Winner, Player’s stash.**

They may, or may not represent a useful object in your representation of blackjack. Some may be obvious objects you need now (Deck, Card, Hand, Player, Dealer); some may be combined (Chip, Bet, Stash); some may not be needed in a modest application (Winner, Bet, Stash), and replaced by data structures, like Lists, Vectors, HashTables, etc.

> 1. Create a **deck** of 52 cards
> 2. Shuffle the deck
> 3. Ask the **Player** for their **bet**
> 4. Make sure that the Player’s bet does not exceed their available **chips**
> 5. Deal two cards to the **Dealer** and two cards to the Player
> 6. Show only one of the Dealer’s cards, the other remains hidden
> 7. Show both of the Player’s cards
> 8. Ask the Player if they wish to Hit, and take another card
> 9. If the Player’s **hand** doesn’t Bust (go over 21), ask if they’d like to Hit again.
> 10. If a Player Stands, play the Dealer’s hand. The dealer will always Hit until the Dealer’s value meets or exceeds 17
> 11. Determine the **winner** and adjust the **Player’s stash** accordingly
> 12. Ask the Player if they’d like to play again

Comment: Thanks Reblochon, that was a great start, will try to implement it. Thanks a tonne!!

Answer (score 0):

You should think in any object you will need in your game, and think about the attributes and actions they will make, for example the Card should have a suit and a value, these are the card attributes. The deck should contain every card and be able to shuffle the cards, so create a method inside your Deck Class that can do this function.

Here i will leave a link so you can have a better understanding of OOP in python.

https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/